# Why is my Leaflet popup closing unexpectedly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, leaflet

I have a feature that allows the user to look up a marker and zoom to its location, at which point I want the popup to open.  Everything is working fine, except that the popup closes after the function fires.  I can't figure out what's making the popup close.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/katherbreen/jL03k4cg/11/) of the issue.  If I take the element ".lookFor" and position is outside of the map div, the feature works correctly; however I need the feature to be where it is.  It's part of a [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) tabbed interface that holds other map tools that sits on what will be a full-screen map.

Here's my relevant code:

```
var geoJsonDataFeatures = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features":[]
};

//create popup content
var htmlString = "<div>popup html goes here....</div>";
var popupContent = L.popup().setContent(htmlString);

//create geoJson object for each marker
var geoJsonData = {
"type": "Feature",
"id": siteNo, //a string saved as a variable 
"properties": {
    "popupContent": popupContent,
    "icon": icon //an L.icon object
    },
"geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [longitude, latitude] //strings saved as variables
    }
}

//push the geoJson feature into the features object
geoJsonDataFeatures.features.push(geoJsonData);

//create the map layer that holds the markers
var geoJsonDataLayer = L.geoJson(geoJsonDataFeatures, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.popupContent);
    layer.setIcon(feature.properties.icon);
    }
}).addTo(map);

....

//when the user has selected a site from a dropdown select menu,
//we pass the site number (siteNo) to a function to zoom and open the
//marker popup:

zoomOpenPopup(siteNo);

function zoomOpenPopup(siteNo){
var marker = {};
var popup = {};
var layerObj = {};

    if(map.hasLayer(geoJsonDataLayer))
    {
    layerObj = geoJsonDataLayer;
    }

    jQuery.each(layerObj._layers, function(k){

        if(siteNo == layerObj._layers[k].feature.id)
        {
        marker = layerObj._layers[k];
        popup = layerObj._layers[k].feature.properties.popupContent;
        }  
    });

marker.openPopup();
//popup._isOpen = true; //doesn't work
//popup.openOn(map); //doesn't work
//map.openPopup(popup); //doesn't work
 alert("done!"); 
}
```

When the alert fires, you can see the popup open on the map, but once the alert is closed the popup disappears.  I do have a function that updates the position of the popup offset on open to reset the popup if it was previously resized to fit content for a Bootstrap tab, but I have the same issue of the popup closing even if I comment out that function and reload the page.  Here's the function:

```
//when a popup opens, set the default offset
map.on("popupopen",function(e){
e.popup.options.offset = L.point(0,-13);
e.popup._updatePosition();
jQuery(".leaflet-popup-content").css("width","301px");
});
```

Has anyone run into something similar?

Comment: Any chance of you posting this live somewhere so we can see the entire flow?

Comment: Sure!  Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/katherbreen/jL03k4cg/11/).  I think the problem may have something to do with the placement of the element ".lookFor" on top of the map.  For my actual site, I have this element inside of a Bootstrap tabbed interface that offers the user multiple tools, and I would like this site-finder tool to be included in that element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your animated `setView` is closing out the popup as part of the `moveend` event.

Instead, try using this code for the button click.It waits until `moveend` is completely done, then preps the popup.

```
jQuery("#lookForButton").click(function(){
    map.on('moveend', function(e) {
        zoomOpenPopup("11486990");
        map.off('moveend');
    });
    map.setView([42.1676459, -121.776391], 14);
});
```

Comment: snkashis - I've been playing with your code, and I'm having trouble.  It works great with just one site, but when I add more I run into the same issues.  See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jL03k4cg/20/).  Any ideas?

Comment: I see - looking it over.

Comment: Looks like your button control was causing issues as well. In the feature use L.Control instead of trying to absolutely position an element on top of the map like that. Try this fiddle and see what I mean. http://jsfiddle.net/v5tq4668/  I also removed your usage of private _latLng in favor of .getLatLng() and also used Leaflet's core eachLayer function instead of  the jquery version.

Comment: Yeah, I tried the same things too.  Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v5tq4668/1/) using a custom control instead of an absolutely positioned element, but it doesn't work.  I appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Add `L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(div);` after `div.innerHTML = lookForHTML;`. Click is falling through to map.

Comment: Thank you!  The feature works perfectly now.  I really appreciate you taking the time to help me on this!